# windows store desktop apps, File encryption algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio-2012, encryption, windows-8

I am developing a project on Windows store desktop apps.
I need to encrypt a file from server and decrypt the file at client side(desktop pc).

Development language for the application is C#.
IDE is "Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows store apps"

What type of Encryption algorithm will be good to implement?

Please provide some samples too as am new to C# coding.

Comment: What about using https ?

Comment: I agree with @KrisVandermotten. SSL/TLS is the way to go. If you want custom encryption, you should do it on top of SSL. But without a clear description of what you want to achieve using encryption, we can't really help you.

Comment: I dont have the budget to purchase an SSL certificate.